# Getting associated comments and reactions Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get associated comment and reaction data from the Facebook API?

e.g. { reaction: "haha", comment: "this is hilarious" }

I'm looking for anonymous data for my dissertation, tying emojis to comments.

Comment: Associated with what exactly? You can not just query stuff any more simply based on that it is “public” - for data from public pages you have no admin access to, you would have to submit for the Page Public Content Access feature first, and anything you want to get from user profiles requires that the user log in to your app and grant it permissions first.

Comment: Reactions and comments that are associated with each other. I.E made by the same user on the same post. I wish to use these associations as labels for training an ML model. Would this be possible then with public pages assuming I get the "Page Public Content Access Feature"?

Comment: I meant associated with what kind of object - post, photo, … // If you only need data from pages (posts on a page feed, with their comments & reactions), then PPCA should do, in theory. But this is something that has to be _approved_ by Facebook in app review, and whether they will grant it, depends on what your purpose is. I rather doubt they will, for this kind of data gathering app.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Just to clarify, assuming I was approved for PPCA and I were to get comment and reaction data for public page posts, the comments and reactions could be aggregated by user? Also If you post an answer I will accept :)

Comment: No, without admin access to the page you will not get any actual user data. You will be able to see comments and reactions, but you can not get info about the user that made them.